# Why do we use bin/magento setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, dicompilation

I know why we use `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

It is recommended on many blogs and forums that we need to execute `bin/magento setup:di:compile` after upgrade command.

It will be great if anyone can tell why do we use this command, what is the purpose behind it?

**bin/magento setup:di:compile**

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-db-upgr.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setup:di:compile` => `Generates DI (Dependency injection) configuration and all missing classes that can be auto-generated`

**Trick:** You can type `php bin/magento`, you'll see all commands with their purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The setup:di:compile command is an integral part of Magento’s 2 command-line interface (CLI). Its primary purpose is to compile the dependency injection (DI) configuration files